# get LCID from string

Tags: c++, windows, locale, crt, lcid

How to get LCID from string like "en-US"?

I know about GetLocaleInfoEx function, but it doesn't work on windows XP.

Can I get LCID from CRT locale?

UPD: Can I convert between [LCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373763%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and CRT locale (created by [_create_locale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zx9aht2%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) function)?   CRT locale may be created by _create_locale and string - Locale name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741018%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Seems to go back as far as IE 4.0, so you should be OK on XP.